# Limit clickcount inside a button - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I clone some form inputs onclick with Jquery. What I want to achieve is, that the counter inside the add-button triggers an event on one of those two buttons. If the count is 0 (zero), i want to disable the add-button and assign a class to it (not-active). If the count is 9, I want to disable the del-button and assign a class to it (not-acitve).

My code looks like this:

```
<button id="add" class="active" type="button">Downcount&nbsp;&#040;<span id="counter">9</span>&#041;</button>
<button id="del" class="active" type="button">Upcount</button>
```

The Jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var upcount = 0;
    var downcount = 0; 
    var start = 9;

    $("#add").click(function() {
    upcount++;
    $("#counter").html(start - upcount + downcount);
    });

  $("#del").click(function() {
    downcount++;
    $("#counter").html(start - upcount + downcount);
    });

});
```

I also made a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/phii/8zf31158/

Can someone help me with an if statement or even a more elegant way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want the opposite. Disable the "down" button when counter is zero and disable "up" button when it's 9. So that you don't cross the 0-9 range. Anyway, you can simply use `$(this).prop('disabled', 1);` to disable the button.

Comment: sure! i want to stay inside the range of 0 to 9. ;) Could you give me a code example to your recomendation? I am really a bloody noob :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method and use only one `counter`.

After that you can create a function who check the value of the `counter` and `disable` your `button`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var counter = 9;
    
  $("#add").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $("#counter").html(counter);
    checkcounter();
  });

  $("#del").click(function() {
    counter--;
    $("#counter").html(counter);
    checkcounter();
  });
  
  function checkcounter()
  {
    if(counter >= 10)
      $("#add").prop("disabled",true);
    else if(counter<=0)
    {
      $("#del").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else
    {
      $("#add").prop("disabled",false);
      $("#del").prop("disabled",false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add" class="active" type="button">Downcount&nbsp;&#040;<span id="counter">9</span>&#041;</button>
<button id="del" class="active" type="button">Upcount</button>
```

Comment: This is even better for my needs - thanks a lot! @Turnip solved it, like it suites my needs in adding classes. But this does the real deal, because it really disables the button when a certain number is reached. I need that, because the button also has to stop cloning inputs. Thank you very much! Best answer. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks once again! I implemented it into my form and it works like a charm.

Comment: @арнонюм No problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8zf31158/15/) as more elegant way to achieve your goal.

```js
var upcount = 9;
function updateCount() {
    $("#counter").html(upcount);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        (upcount < 9) && upcount++;
        updateCount();
    });
    $("#del").click(function() {
        (upcount > 0) && upcount--;
        updateCount();
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="del" class="active" type="button">Downcount&nbsp;&#040;<span id="counter">9</span>&#041;</button>
<button id="add" class="active" type="button">Upcount</button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```